# Erro "Your login SYSDBA is same as one of the SQL role name" ao tentar acessar base com IBExpert

Tags: firebird

Preciso acessar os dados de uma base do Firebird, porém ao tentar acessar esta base utilizando o IBExpert obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Your login SYSDBA is same as one of the SQL role name.

Em pesquisas que realizei, descobri que este erro se trata de uma `ROLE` que foi criada com o mesmo nome do usuário padrão do Firebird, impossibilitando que eu consiga acessar esta base com o usuário padrão.

Dentre as soluções para este problema, não obtive sucesso com nenhuma, mas a que achei mais plausível seria editar diretamente o `.FDB` via algum editor de texto dando um `REPLACE` nas ocorrências de `SYSDBA`, porém também não consegui aplicar esta solução mesmo o arquivo estando com o "*somente leitura*" desmarcado.

Alguém saberia uma maneira de conseguir dropar esta ROLE ou contorna-la?

Estou usando o Firebird 2.5, versão 32bits em um S.O. 64bits.

Comment: Ficou faltando explicar quais soluções você tentou e não conseguiu êxito.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o `isql.exe` que está no diretório de instalação do Firebird.

```sql
SQL> CONNECT "C:\CAMINHO\NOMEDOBANCO.FDB" 
SQL> user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
```

Ou você pode criar um usuário novo e dar direitos de admin para ele.

```sql
GRANT RDB$ADMIN TO username.
```